# How can I fix the offset on this object so it lines up with the animation?

Tags: animation, armature

I have this character:

[image]

He has an armature and an animation, and his sword, shown at the bottom, has to be loaded in separately.  I tried to parent the sword to the armature.  There's a bone and a vertex group labeled bn_r_weapon_melee01, and it looks like that's the correct bone, but during the animation, this happens:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It looks like the sword is moving and rotating MOSTLY properly, but it's offset from the character's hand incorrectly.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Hello could you  please share the armature and the sword (no need for the robot object)?

Comment: Can I just upload a .blend file?

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant, but you can remove the robot mesh if you prefer not to share it

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to pare down the file to get under Blend-Exchange's 30MB limit.  I want to delete the robot's mesh but leave the armature and animation alone.

Comment: or use another platform like workupload and share the link

Comment: Thanks for being patient:
https://www.mediafire.com/file_premium/8c5ll4yow96pt68/sm_wip_2023-11-04.blend/file

Comment: Why are your bones so huge, I'm afraid I don't understand your armature setup

Comment: I know...the file imported that way.  I'm not sure what to do about that.

Comment: parent the sword to the empty called attachment_r_01 and make sure that it's correctly placed and rotated?

Comment: I tried that, and with attachment_r_02, and with the right hand.  I get some rotations, all incorrect, and then the sword disappears about 40 frames into the animation.

Comment: Yes attachment_r_02 instead, see my answer, it seems to work fine

Comment: It's not working with me.  What are you selecting when you parent it?  With empty groups, with automatic weights, etc.?

Comment: Deactivate the Auto-Keying option of the timeline which is a bit annoying, at frame 50 for example, select the sword, shift select the empty, parent with Ctrl P, then move the sword until it is correctly placed in the hand

Answer (score 0):

Parent the sword to the empty called *attachment_r_02* and move the sword until the hand grabs it and it seems to work pretty fine. If the sword disappears it's because the empty scales down, change its keyframes if you don't want that.

[image]

Other method, select your sword, shift select the robot object, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices of its palm and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*:

[image]

Correctly place the sword in the hand:

[image]

Comment: That looks right, but it doesn't work for me.  The sword has a bunch of incorrect rotations and locations for about 40 frames, and then it disappears.  It also starts in the wrong position.

Comment: in that case use another method like parenting the sword to 3 vertices of the hand, I'm going to edit